# Redirect var/reports/* to stdout

Tags: log

I am using Magento 1.9 and want to redirect all the files generated inside the folder var/reports to stdout. If it is possible then how can I do it? If it is not then may be we can output all the generated reports files to one file and symlink to /dev/stdout. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE:**

I was able to create a file with name 9999 and redirect all logs to same file but when I tried to symlink the file to `/dev/stdout` or `/proc/self/fd/1`, both does not work. I still need  the way to forward the logs to standard output.

To redirect logs to a single file, open `errors/processor.php` file and edit two lines

```
//$this->reportId   = abs(intval(microtime(true) * rand(100, 1000)));
$this->reportId   = 9999;
```

and

```
//@file_put_contents($this->_reportFile, serialize($reportData));
@file_put_contents($this->_reportFile, serialize($reportData).PHP_EOL,FILE_APPEND|LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. I was actually applying this for kubernetes and I needed to log in stdout. I followed the above updated steps and then use another container as sidecar, then `tail` the output of 9999. It then gave me what I wanted.

I know this is not where I ask devops stuff but here is what sidecar container look like

```
        - image: busybox
          name: report-log
          command: ["/bin/sh"]
          args:
          - -c
          - |
            mkdir -p  /var/www/html/var/report
            touch /var/www/html/var/report/9999
            chown 33:33 /var/www/html/var -R
            chmod 777 /var/www/html/var/ -R
            tail -n+1 -f /var/www/html/var/report/9999
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: 5m
              memory: 64Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 5m
              memory: 64Mi
          volumeMounts:
          - name: reportlog
            mountPath: /var/www/html/var/report
```

Also do  not forget to  mount volume as emptyDir. You can get the example here: https://kiwee.eu/magento-2-on-kubernetes/

Comment: Since I was using kubernetes, I managed to solved it using kubernetes approach. If it can be solved by magento itself then please feel free to leave your comments.

Comment: https://github.com/graycoreio/magento2-stdlogging